# Посчитать количество парных и нечетных чисел, количество положительных и отрицательных

Tags: c#

Пользователь с клавиатуры вводит целые числа (числа вводятся поочередно, пользователь вводя число нажимает «Enter»). Последовательность чисел завершается введением значение «0». Посчитать количество парных и нечетных чисел, количество положительных и отрицательных.
C#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
    Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
    int n, even, odd;
    even = 0; // чет
    odd = 0; // нечет
    Console.WriteLine("Введіть числa: ");
    n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    while (n > 0) 
    {
        if (n % 2 == 0) even += 1;
        else odd += 1;
            n = n / 10;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Додатніх чисел {0}", even);
    Console.WriteLine("Від'ємних чисел {0}", odd);
}
```

Comment: я не знаю как сделать чтобы пользователь с клавиатуры вводил целые числа (числа вводятся поочередно,
пользователь вводя число нажимает «Enter»).

Comment: Скопируйте вот эту строчку `n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` в конец вашего цикла и все дела.

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
        Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
        int inputNumber = int.MinValue;
        List<int> listInputedNumber = new List<int>();
        while (inputNumber != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введіть числa. Для завершения введите \"0\": ");
            if (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out inputNumber))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Не удалось считать информацию. Введите целое число.");
                inputNumber = int.MinValue;
            }
            else
            {
                if (inputNumber == 0)
                {
                   break;
                }
                else
                {
                    listInputedNumber.Add(inputNumber);
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Додатніх чисел {0}", listInputedNumber.Count(n=>n % 2 == 0));
        Console.WriteLine("Від'ємних чисел {0}", listInputedNumber.Count(n => n % 2 != 0));
        Console.WriteLine("Положительных чисел {0}", listInputedNumber.Count(n => n > 0));
        Console.WriteLine("Отрицательных чисел {0}", listInputedNumber.Count(n => n < 0));
}
```

Правда в этом случае числа с плавающей точкой будут считываться как целые без уведомления пользователя. Если это нужно делать тогда на вход нужен Double.

Answer (score 1):

Просто нужно читать числа в цикле. Для решения этой задачи числа хранить не нужно.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int even,odd,negative,positive;
            even=0;
            odd=0;
            negative=0;
            positive=0;
            int a=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            while (a!=0){
                if (a % 2==0){even++;}
                         else{odd++;}
                if (a>0){positive++;}
                if (a<0){negative++;}
                a=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("even={0}, odd={1}, positive={2}, negative={3}",even,odd,positive,negative);

        }
```